# Formatting a question

Tags: support, questions, design

I have written several questions and answers on the gaming site. I often need to provide a link or spoiler mark down a passage of text, but I don’t know how to do it. Is there a page going through all of the formatting options I have when I answer or ask a question?

I've tried the faq but I can't find it there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The markdown help page is on the "Ask Question" page itself, actually.

[image]

And here's a direct link to the [advanced help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help) link.